# How do I start building my reputation?

Tags: discussion

One day, I wanted to up-vote an answer because it was so helpful, but couldn't because I didn't have enough reputation. A little while later, I wanted to answer a question because I was feeling helpful, but couldn't again. Later, I wanted to comment on an answer because I thought there could be a little more clarification with still no success. So, how do I get those first few points that will open the world of stack-fun-times up to me?

Comment: Once you break through the initial barrier of 15 rep (really not very much) most of the significant restrictions (basically the ones to stop spammers) go away *really fast*.

Comment: Folks, this isn't a "find the most duplicates" challenge. Find *one* appropriate duplicate, preferably the most helpful, and target that. I'm using gnat's offering, since it sounds the most pertinent.

Comment: Why couldn't you answer the question you wanted to answer?

Comment: Alright, so meta time: asking this question has gotten me 13 points. I still couldn't up vote answers, so hopefully adding a comment it will get me 2 more!

Comment: Pro-tip: Don't bump your questions just to bump them. If you _are_ going to bump them just to bump them, really, don't _say_ that's what you're doing. Even worse, bumping in the hopes of more rep and stating as much. (This tends to backfire, as you're seeing.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is going to get closed anyway but meh.

From the fact you're asking on meta, it looks like you have *a clue* which is always a start.

*Personally* If you just want the 
minimum amount of reputation to level up, its not *that* hard - I literally got to 191 from one simple answer (which required no programming skills, and periodic maintainance) and my association bonus (which you can get from getting 200 on *any* site - and you can pick one with less traffic than SO)

I've always found that folks who don't do that great here focus on *asking* questions - not answering them.

I experimented a bit (a little too successfully) with a [fresh sock](https://superuser.com/users/264220/aibobot) and found a few interesting things.

Firstly, editing is a *terrible* way to get reputation. Edit cause the mistakes annoy you, not because you're trying to nickle and dime reputation.

Sometimes you get reputation due to sheer dumb luck - aka a HNQ. After a while you can semi work out what sort of questions get there, and often they are soft questions.

And at the end of the day, reputation is just a number. Focus on *answering* questions you know (and if someone posts a better answer, learn from it!), searching for, then asking questions when you *don't* know, and let the reputation roll in organically.

If you want to *game* things the right way, answer fast, edit to what you know your audience wants, and chase bounties. Have funtimes. Level up funtimes will come themselves.